# What can I use to show a Word file in an Access form instead of a Bound Object Frame control?

Tags: ms-access

first of all I let you know that I asked [the same question in Learn Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1105922/what-can-i-use-to-show-a-word-file-in-an-access-fo.html) (but I didn't received any answer yet).

This is my problem.
To simplify a lot my Access database stores Word files.
In the back end there are tables with records having also an OLE object (linked) in their fields.
In the front end there are forms showing in a tab page the Word file of the record in a Bound Object Frame control.

This solution is unsatisfactory because:

- OLE Objects tend to bloat files;
- files stored in the cloud cannot be shown in the control;
- it's impossible to scroll through the file text. (Few lines of text are well readble, a full page has fonts too small).

What can I use instead.
I can have the full path name of the Word file stored in a field of the record.
But how to show the content of the file on the Access form? And possibly to be able to scroll it?

I would appreciate any suggestions
Thanks, Lauro

Comment: If this an option for you, you could store the document as HTML. You can then display it   in a `TextBox` with the `TextFormat` property to set to `RichText`. This sounds strange but the TextBox effectively uses HTML and not RTF as you may expect.